# How to pick a profile picture like Kik?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimage, profile

I want to get some area of a picture and make them to be a profile picture. just like Kik did. How can i implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not ask a question like you are asking a whole feature! Emphasize on a specific area or piece of code. Secondly, you can use `UIImagePicker` to let the user pick image from his IPhone and then use the returned object of `UIImage` for your display pic area. Further details of `UIImagePicker` can be viewed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Happy Coding..!

Comment: thanks, it's my fault, i have not described question clearly. Just like you said, UIImagePickerController does the same thing, we just need to turn on the allowsediting=YES property. But i am not take picture from imagepickercontroller but my own gallery.

Comment: No problem brother. What you mean by own gallery? Does `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` is not suitable enough?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Kik did, but here's how you create a new UIImage from a segment of another UIImage.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"];
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50); // 50x50 in the top left corner.
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([myImage CGImage], myRect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Alternatively, you can tell the UIImageView you're displaying the image in to automatically crop.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```